# How to properly end a KDE session from shell without root privileges

Tags: linux, shell, login, kde, opensuse

I am accessing the machine (OpenSuse 11 with KDE) over NX.

I cannot use the Alt-Ctrl-Del shortcuts as it is captured by my system. The regular logoff button just ends the NX session without ending the KDE session. I cant call `kdm restart` as I have no root privileges.

Other wild guesses like `logout` and `exit` do not work either, the first one complaining about not being in a login shell and the second one just closing the console.

My shell-fu is weak, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See also [How can I safely shutdown/reboot/logout KDE from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1871)

Comment: @MartinSchröder - ah, good catch - it's essentially the same question. But Paul's answer to this question is more exhaustive that Gilles' answer to the other one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can send a logout command via dbus to KDE, which should (if it can) terminate the session.

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

dbus is a messaging system that lets applications communicate with each other, and the `qdbus` command is a utility for sending dbus messages to applications.

Applications register with dbus, and the `ksmserver` part of KDE is the session manager - it looks after who is logged in.

So we are sending a message to `ksmserver` to the `/KSMServer` interface and telling it to logout.  The message we are sending is the exact same message that is sent to KSM when you click on the logout icon on your desktop.

The three zeros are parameters and can alter the type of logout we are doing:

First parameter:

- 0 = Do not wait for confirmation
- 1 = Wait for confirmation (with a 30 second timeout)

Second parameter:

- -1 = Prompt for action, defaulting to shutdown (Only makes sense when waiting for confirmation.)
- 0 = Logout
- 1 = Restart
- 2 = Shutdown

The third parameter is the "when" parameter, but it isn't clear what its impact is.

Comment: Make sure to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable (most likely to `:0`) before you run this command, otherwise it will complain.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is a solution specific for KDE5, a more generic approach would be

```
loginctl list-sessions
loginctl terminate-session <id>
```

or

```
loginctl terminate-user <username>
```

[Source](https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/logout-from-different-desktop-environments-from-command-line/)

There are more possible commands:

```
Session Commands:
  list-sessions            List sessions
  session-status [ID...]   Show session status
  show-session [ID...]     Show properties of sessions or the manager
  activate [ID]            Activate a session
  lock-session [ID...]     Screen lock one or more sessions
  unlock-session [ID...]   Screen unlock one or more sessions
  lock-sessions            Screen lock all current sessions
  unlock-sessions          Screen unlock all current sessions
  terminate-session ID...  Terminate one or more sessions
  kill-session ID...       Send signal to processes of a session

User Commands:
  list-users               List users
  user-status [USER...]    Show user status
  show-user [USER...]      Show properties of users or the manager
  enable-linger [USER...]  Enable linger state of one or more users
  disable-linger [USER...] Disable linger state of one or more users
  terminate-user USER...   Terminate all sessions of one or more users
  kill-user USER...        Send signal to processes of a user

Seat Commands:
  list-seats               List seats
  seat-status [NAME...]    Show seat status
  show-seat [NAME...]      Show properties of seats or the manager
  attach NAME DEVICE...    Attach one or more devices to a seat
  flush-devices            Flush all device associations
  terminate-seat NAME...   Terminate all sessions on one or more seats
```

Comment: But this approach terminates the whole desktop session.

Comment: love systemd. this opens so many more questions. what is a session? X? what is a seat?